# why can't access some of android.R.drawables?

Tags: android

I'm creating my applications. but i want to use android default drawables icon (calendar, camera or etc...)

some of icons can be use.

but some of cannot.

here is my code

[image]

android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera it's okay to use.

but android.R.drawable.ic_menu_cc_am is error in Android studio

[image]

this file(ic_menu_cc_am) exists in android sdk and can jump to declaration like this.

[image]

why I can't use of this file (some of files also can't using on android studio, but file is exists!)

sorry for my bad english.

thank you.

Comment: "this file(ic_menu_cc_am) exists in android sdk " -- not according to the JavaDocs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. I have checked only android-sdk.jar file. this is my fault.

Comment: It depends on the OS version. And some icons are not accessible anyway, because their references aren't made public.

Comment: @BobMalooga thanks for your comment. I figured out

Comment: It would be great if you could write an answer to document your findings if someone else encounters the same problem.